# Azure DevOps - Running scheduled task with existing CI pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, scheduled-tasks, cicd, dependabot

If I wanted to run a scheduled task once a month for checking for outdated dependencies but I already have a CI pipeline how can I do that? For example I have a pipeline that runs though code sniffs -> checkmarx + twistlock -> deploy to dev -> stage and whatnot. This triggers on master. I want to also include the ability to have a scheduled task of dependabot to occur once every month. How can I mix this scheduled task into an established CI pipeline? This is all contained within Azure Devops as well.

I only want to run the single task of dependabot once a month. I don't want to run the entire pipeline once a month

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a second - entirely separate - pipeline to run dependabot once a month.

That way, you can have the appropriate triggers for the CI pipeline, and the appropriate schedule for the dependabot pipeline, with exactly the right tasks in each one and no duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a pipeline using both the trigger and schedules.

For example, to run a stage on the 1st day of every month at 08:00 UTC, you can use:

```
 trigger:
- master  #This is the trigger for other stages. It is not needed for the scheduled stage.

schedules:
- cron: '0 8 1 * *'
  displayName: 'Deploy every 1st day of every month at 08:00Z'
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true
```

Then, to ensure that a specific stage runs as part of the scheduled run, use the condition expression, for example:

```
- stage: 'Test'
  displayName: 'Deploy to the test environment'
  dependsOn: Dev
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

Refer to this MSDocs article for more on the syntax of schedules: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers

Comment: Thank you for the response! However, I am looking to run my dependabot task only and not the entire pipeline. I want dependabot to never run within the pipeline except for once a month and at that point, to be the only task that is run.

Comment: I just edited the answer :-) In my own solution I make use of stages with conditions to specify when they should run.  "condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')" should satisfy that need.  I believe you can use the 'condition expression' directly with a Task also.

Comment: Using this condition expression, will ensure that the task only runs for scheduled events (it is skipped otherwise).  Unfortunately I'm not too sure how to prevent the other tasks from running (with future merges on Master) after the 1st run of your scheduled tasks...