# Can I schedule a pipeline to check out a different branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm writing a new pipeline that does vulnerability testing on our project. I want to schedule the pipeline to run periodically. That part is not a problem; the syntax is pretty clear:

```yaml
schedules:
- cron: string # cron syntax defining a schedule
  displayName: string # friendly name given to a specific schedule
  branches:
    include: [ string ] # which branches the schedule applies to
    exclude: [ string ] # which branches to exclude from the schedule
  always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.
  batch: boolean # Whether to run the pipeline if the previously scheduled run is in-progress; the default is false.
  # batch is available in Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 and higher
```

However, this part may be tricky. My vulnerability testing pipeline will be in branch `vulnerability_testing`, and I want it to do its testing on the `main` branch.

That is:

- the scheduler triggers,
- the `vulnerability_testing` branch gets checked out,
- the vulnerability testing pipeline gets loaded,
- then the `main` branch gets checked out,
- and the pipeline runs against the files in the `main` branch.

I don't think the `schedules` syntax supports that. Will I need to do an additional `checkout` step in the pipeline? And if I do, will I then lose the pipeline, because it may or may not exist in the `main` branch?

Comment: have you tried wrapping your schedule with a task? You would have two tasks with  schedule defined each operating on the required branch

Comment: On second thought, check out the answer and comments for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70656515/4215616). It might be a better approach.

Comment: Branches are not meant to contain permanent, ongoing deviations from your trunk. Why can't you merge your pipeline into the `main` branch?

Comment: @DanielMann I don't have a good answer for that. That's certainly what I plan to do in the long run. But for now I want to leave `main` untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ShamraiAleksander's suggestion to checkout additional repository resources from the `main` branch should work based on your requirement.

There will be another issue when checking out sources from different branches in the **same** repo, that the second checkout step will overwrite the contents checked out during the first step. The trick is to separate the paths for the two checkout steps, as introduced in [Checkout path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path)

[image]

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: BranchSources
    type: git
    name: RepoA
    ref: main
steps:
- checkout: self
  path: vulnerability_testing
- checkout: BranchSources
  path: main
- script: |
    tree $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, consider using multiple repositories([Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)). Use separate repo for yamls and define something similar:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: sources
    type: git
    name: repo_with_main_branch
    ref: main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: sources
```